# Rectangle functions in emacs

Tags: emacs

I've read in several places that the rectangle functions in emacs are very useful. I've read a bit about them, and I can't quite figure why. I mean, when you want to kill a paragraph, you mark the first row/column and then the last one, and  that's actually a rectangle, right? But you can still use the normal kill...

So what kind of transformations would you do with them?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you have data in columns in a text file with `M-x delete-rectangle` or `M-x kill-rectangle` you can delete a single column of data.  Similarly, `M-x yank-rectangle` will paste in a column of text.

For example, take the following text:

```
1. alligator    alphorn
2. baboon       bugle
3. crocodile    cornet
4. dog          didgeridoo
5. elephant     euphonium 
6. fish         flugelhorn   
7. gopher       guitar
```

Select from the a of alligator to the g of guitar.  The beginning and end of the selection mark out two opposite corners of the rectangle.  Enter `M-x kill-rectangle` and you immediately have:

```
1. alphorn
2. bugle
3. cornet
4. didgeridoo
5. euphonium 
6. flugelhorn
7. guitar
```

Next put the mark at the end of the top line, add a few spaces if required and enter `M-x yank-rectangle` and ta-da!  You have re-ordered the columns:

```
1. alphorn      alligator    
2. bugle        baboon       
3. cornet       crocodile    
4. didgeridoo   dog          
5. euphonium    elephant     
6. flugelhorn   fish         
7. guitar       gopher
```

Answer (score 15):

I like to use rectangle for 2 main purposes, inserting the same text on every line, or killing a column of text (similar to Dave Webb's answer).

There are 2 useful shortcuts for these, `C-x r k` will kill a rectangle, and `C-x r t` to insert (there are other rectangle commands with a `C-x r` prefix, but these are the ones I use).

So let's say you want to take some code and format it so that you can post it in a Stack Overflow post... you need to prefix with 4 spaces.  So, go to the beginning of the first line, `C-SPC` to mark, then go to the beginning of the last line and `C-x r t <SPC> <SPC> <SPC> <SPC> <RET>`, and there you have it!  Then you can just copy and paste it into Stack Overflow.  I have run into more complex situations where this is useful, where you actually have text you want to insert on every line at a particular place.

So the other situation like Dave Webb's situation, if you want to kill a rectangle, use `C-x r k` though, because it's just a lot quicker ;-)

Also, according to my [reference card](http://refcards.com/docs/gildeas/gnu-emacs/emacs-refcard-a4.pdf) that I printed out when I first started, you can do the following:

- `C-x r r`: copy to a register
- `C-x r y`: yank a rectangle
- `C-x r o`: open a rectangle, shifting text right (whatever that means...)
- `C-x r c`: blank out a rectangle (I assume that means replace it with spaces, but you'd have to try it out to see)
- `C-x r t`: prefix with text (as described above)
- `C-x r k`: killing (as described above)

Comment: I have partial-completion-mode switched on so for yank-rectangle I can use M-x y-r [tab] [ret] but you're right, the default shortcuts are quicker.

Comment: Wow... you use Emacs for 20 odd years and there's still new stuff to learn.

Comment: "C-x r t RETURN SPACE SPACE SPACE SPACE RETURN" The first return seems to be an error? I get the desired effect when typing: C-x r t SPACE SPACE SPACE SPACE RETURN

Answer (score 2):

In emacs24+ there's also function for numbering lines:

```
(rectangle-number-lines START END START-AT &optional FORMAT)

Insert numbers in front of the region-rectangle.

START-AT, if non-nil, should be a number from which to begin
counting.  FORMAT, if non-nil, should be a format string to pass
to `format' along with the line count.  When called interactively
with a prefix argument, prompt for START-AT and FORMAT.
```

It is binded to <kbd>C-x r N</kbd> by default.